# Monte Carlo Simulation giving 0 as output

Tags: python, statistics, montecarlo

I ran an experiment in which I got 6 different orders of size and now I'm trying to see if my observations are significant. I have to perform a MC simulation to get a p value to see if my observed values are unusually large or small compared to the null.

I need to:

- Set up a scheme where Order 1 is 0 to 1/6, Order 2, is 1/6- to 2/6, order 3 is 2/6 to 3/6
- Generate 20 random numbers between 0 and 1 and allocate them to these bins.  If the number if < 1/6 put it in bin 1, if it is between 1/6 and 2/6 into bin 2 etc.  -

I should have 6 new numbers, one for each bin, that add up to 20, but my output is saying 0. Im new to python so what am I doing wrong?

My code is here:

```
from random import randint
from random import seed

# seed random number generator
seed(1)
counter = 0
chi_sq_values = []
# want 10,000 simulations
while counter < 10000:
    # will eventually mimic your real six orders of size
    sim_orders = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    # generating 20 random numbers
    for i in range(20):
        numbers = randint(0, 1)
        if 0 <= numbers <= 1 / 6:
            numbers += sim_orders[0]
        if 1 / 6 <= numbers <= 2 / 6:
            numbers += sim_orders[1]
        if 2 / 6 <= numbers <= 3 / 6:
            numbers += sim_orders[2]
        if 3 / 6 <= numbers <= 4 / 6:
            numbers += sim_orders[3]
        if 4 / 6 <= numbers <= 5 / 6:
            numbers += sim_orders[4]
        if 5 / 6 <= numbers <= 6 / 6:
            numbers += sim_orders[5]

    print(sim_orders)
```

Comment: There are quite a lot of things that are wrong in this code. `counter += 1` is not written and `sim_orders = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` they are all 0's and you are not changing their value ever so how will `print(sim_orders)` give anything anything but `[0,0,0,0,0,0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not incrementing the values in `sim_orders`. You're adding the value in `sim_orders`  to `numbers`, which has no effect because the value is always `0`. And then you're not doing anything with `numbers` after you add to it.

You should increment the appropriate counter in `sim_orders`.

You need to use `random.random()`, not `random.randint(0, 1)`. The latter will just return `0` or `1`, not a number between 0 and 1.

```
    for i in range(20):
        numbers = random.random()
        if numbers <= 1 / 6:
            sim_orders[0] += 1
        elif numbers <= 2 / 6:
            sim_orders[1] += 1
        elif numbers <= 3 / 6:
            sim_orders[2] += 1
        elif numbers <= 4 / 6:
            sim_orders[3] += 1
        elif numbers <= 5 / 6:
            sim_orders[4] += 1
        else:
            sim_orders[5] += 1
```

You should also use `elif` for a sequence of mutually exclusive conditions, to avoid unnecessary tests. And if you do this, you don't need to test both ends of the range, since the previous test precludes numbers lower than the bottom of the range.

Your conditions overlapped -- if `numbers` was an exact multiple of `1/6` it would be put into both bins.

You can also get rid of all the `if` statements entirely:

```
    sim_orders[floor(numbers*6)] += 1
```

Comment: I tried this but its only adding numbers to the [0] and [5] position of sim_orders. The elif point is a good one, thanks!

Comment: Because you used `randint` instead of `random`

Comment: Ah thank you: that's odd because an online guide told me to use randint! One other question: how do I make my code stop running once it reaches 10,000 simulations? It currently keeps going forever

Comment: You're never incrementing `counter`. Use `for counter in range(10000):`

Comment: Are you sure the online guide was showing how to generate numbers *between* 0 and 1?

Comment: Where should for counter in range go in my code? 
Also the online guide said this: Random integer values can be generated with the randint() function. Random integers are generated within and including the start and end of range values, specifically in the interval [start, end].

Comment: In place of `while counter < 10000:`

Comment: Read what you just wrote: "random **integer** values can be generated". Numbers between 0 and 1 are not integers.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has helped- I was following an example my instructor gave me, but this method makes more sense

Comment: You can keep your `while`, just add `counter += 1` to the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to update your list **sim_orders**  with zeros, then you should put it **out of** while cycle. Moreover I don't see where you update your list with generated numbers. And if you want your while cycle to be finite then you have to increment counter inside loop body.